# Binance api websockets

Tags: python, websocket, binance-api-client

i have a problem. i need to get 5 candles info in one request but here i get one and before second update speed is too big for my application so i need to get 5 candles info in one requests

i have a code like this how i can add limit to link or thms other

```
import json
import websocket

# websocket.enableTrace(True) #uncomment for debug

def on_open(ws):
    print("open")

def on_message(ws,message):
    json_message = json.loads(message) 
    candle = json_message['data']['k']  
    print(message)
    is_candle_closed = candle['x']
    if is_candle_closed:
        print(json.dumps(candle, indent=2))

def on_close(ws, close_status_code, close_msg):
    print("closed")
  
SOCK = "wss://stream.binance.com:9443/stream?streams=btcusdt@kline_1m"


ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(SOCK, on_open=on_open,on_close=on_close, on_message=on_message)
ws.run_forever()
```